# Tic Tac Toe Game problem with computer move

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing tic tac toe game and I have such a problem because I created the computerMove function and it is responsible for creating an "O" in a random field. But when there is the last field to choose and there is a player's move, when you click on this field as a player, a second "O" appears in another. Sometimes two "O" appear in the middle of the game.

Here is a link to the whole project: https://codepen.io/daniel-led/pen/qBZpWZG

```
let pools = document.querySelectorAll(".pool"); 
let randomNumber;
var nums = [];
    ranNums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
// let i = 0;
let didHave;

addClickForPools();

function addClickForPools(){ //addEventListener
    for(let i = 0; i < pools.length; i++){
        pools[i].addEventListener("click", userMove);

        function userMove(){
            let h1 = document.createElement("H1");
            let t = document.createTextNode("X")
            h1.appendChild(t);
            pools[i].appendChild(h1);
            nums[i] = i;
            
                computerMove();
              
            removeClickForPools();
            // pools[i].innerHTML = 
            function removeClickForPools(){
                pools[i].removeEventListener("click", userMove);
            }
        }
    }

}
function computerMove(){

   randomNumber = randomNum();


   
    let h1 = document.createElement("H1");
    let t = document.createTextNode("O")
    h1.appendChild(t);
    pools[randomNumber].appendChild(h1);
   

    
  
}


function randomNum(){
    let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    didHave = nums.includes(n);

    while(didHave == true){
         n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        didHave = nums.includes(n);
    }
    nums.push(n);
    return n
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on Gordon's answer and why mixing `nums.push(n)` and `nums[i] = i` is a problem.. `nums.push(n)` always appends to the end of `nums`, so if `nums` has 3 items a fourth will be added to the end. `nums[i] = i` is direct assignment to a slot so a user move can override the computers move. That's why the computer places O's in slots it already played. Always use `push` to append items to an array in JS.

The second issue I see is that `randomNum()` should also be able to return 0, as that represents the first tile and the computer should be able to play that.

You also need to check if the computer should play at all - if there are any empty tiles left.

[I made some edits to your codepen.](https://codepen.io/warhammered_cat/pen/gOroYVX)

Answer (score 0):

You add the pool number in `nums` in the function `userMove()` through `nums[i] = i;`, but in the function `randomNum()` through `nums.push(n);`. You should use the same way in the both methods.